# Processing (multithreading) socket server new serverSocket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, processing

I am trying to create a client-server communication in processing.
This is a stripped version of the server.pde:

```
cThread thread;
ServerSocket socket1;
int main_sid = 0;
int main_port = 5204;

void setup() {
  size(300, 400);
  try {
    ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket(main_port);
  } catch (Exception g) { }
}

void draw() {
  try{
          Socket main_cnn = socket1.accept();
          thread = new cThread(main_cnn,main_sid,20);
          thread.start();
          println("New client: " + main_cnn.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " Assigned sid: " + main_sid);
          main_sid++;

  } catch (Exception g) { }
}

class cThread extends Thread { ...
```

The setup loop is supposed to initialise the `ServerSocket` and the draw loop should try accepting clients continuously.

The problem is `ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket(main_port);`
It should only initialise once, but does not work when putting it in the setup like this.

What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring as a Field and next you declare as local in setup...

If you declare a local variable with the same signature of another "global"/field like you did

```
ServerSocket socket1;
...
void setup()
{
 ...
   ServerSocket socket1... /* here you want to use the socket above...
   but you declare a socket variable with the same signature,
   so to compiler will ignore the field above and will use your local
   variable...

   When you try to use the field he will be null because you do not affected
   your state.*/
```

The Java will give priority to the local one!

The right way:

```
void setup()
{
    size(300, 400);
    try
    {/* now you are using the field socket1 and not a local socket1 */
        socket1 = new ServerSocket(main_port);
    }
   catch (Exception g) { }
}
```

Comment: It will happen even if the 'signature', by which you mean 'type', is different. It's simply a question of scope, not 'priority'. There is nothing 'right' about ignoring an exception.